# ¿Qué significa "por" en el eslogan "Es por ti"?

Tags: traducción, definiciones

### Español

En una clase de español hemos hablado del uso de "por" y "para". De camino a casa esto me ha recordado de un eslogan de la compañía de vuelo Avianca que he visto: "Es por ti."

No estoy seguro del significado de "por". Si significaría "it's for you" habría sido "es *para* ti". Dado la presencia de la palabra "por" pienso que significa "it's thanks to you" o "it's because of you" ("es gracias a ti") o algo así.

¿Cuál sería la mejor interpretación?
Si es "it's because of you", ¿sería muy diferente de decir "es para ti"?

[image]

### English

During a Spanish lesson we talked about the usage of "por" and "para". On the way home this reminded me of a slogan of the flight company Avianca I once saw: "Es por ti."
I am unsure about the meaning of "por" here. If it would mean "it's for you" it would have been "es *para* ti". So given the use of "por" I'm starting to think it means "it's thanks to you" or "it's because of you" or something. What would be the best interpretation?
If it is "it's because of you" would "es para ti" sound much different?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about translations into English.

Comment: As you can imagine, on a web site about Spanish, translations *into English* are off-topic.  If your real question is "What does 'por ti' mean?" that can be asked and adequately answered without asking for an English translation.

Comment: Good edit! I have re-opened your question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The meaning of "es por ti" is "you are the cause of this"

> Es por ti que late mi corazón

but "Es por ti" could also convey "es para ti"

> Es por ti que tenemos estos asientos tan cómodo, porque nos importas, porque lo mereces.

In this case it can also mean that you are cause and recipient (for being such a wonderful customer we are going to give you this awesome treatment).

So I would translate as

> Es por ti

and take advantage of this "es para ti" meaning.

Comment: I think there is also another possibility: it's for *your good/benefit*, like in *es por ti que trabajo tan duro* when you are actually working for someone else

Answer (score 3):

Avianca, the airline, is giving the reason for all their efforts:

> It is because of you

I just remembered a song by Juanes: [Es por tí](http://youtu.be/-9l5t3MWss8)... all a lover does because of the loved one.